# WPF / C# : Delte Items from List<> in a DataGrid via Button

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid

> > Hello World,

I am creating a DataGrid out of my List<> Fills, now i want to delete an element from my List<> Fills but got a

**System.InvalidCastException: Object of the typ "TreeviewList.DataGridFill" can not be converted in "System.Iconvertible".**

(System.InvalidCastException: "Das Objekt des Typs "TreeviewList.DataGridFill" kann nicht in Typ "System.IConvertible" umgewandelt werden.")

Error message.

I want to select a Row in the DataGrid and delete the Item from my List<> Fills, after that the DataGrid should be just showing the new Data without the deleted one.

Here is my Code for the Delete Button:

```
private void Button_Click_Delete(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var selectedItem = DataGridList.SelectedItem;

        if (DataGridList.SelectedItem != null)
        {

            /* And here is the Error message showing up */
            Fills.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt32(selectedItem));

            /* Update the DataGrid with the new List<> Data */
            DataGridList.ItemsSource = Fills;

        }
    }
```

> > Maybe someone has an idea to solve my problem.
> >
> > Thank you <3
> >
> > Best Regards,  Blackbear

Comment: Why don't you replace the `List<T>` with an `ObservableCollection<T>` and simply delete the item from this one?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SelectedItem is some model class, but you're trying to convert it to Int32 somehow? If SelectedItem is an item from the list, just use the [.Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.7.2) method and pass it the object you want to remove.